# Standard app engine maven plugin appengine:run restarts spring boot application multiple times

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, appengine-maven-plugin

I am facing weird issue with standard app engine and spring boot application generated using jhipster. When I am trying to run appengine:run on my local system, application is initiated by maven plugin multiple times and then it fails as datasource instance is already initiated. 
Due to which it's difficult to debug the issues with application. Recently I added google search API. And to debug the same I need to run it locally.
The same application runs without any issues on cloud.

Anyone has any idea what could be wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by reducing scaling instances to 1. It's not actually issue. It was initializing due to scaling specified in appengine-web.xml